# How to check object relation is populated without catching DoesNotExist

Tags: django

I have a one to one relationship defined on a model.  Let's call the parent model A and the related model B.  B will not always exist.  When I'm interacting with an instance of A how can I determine if B exists without having to catch DoesNotExist?  When I attempt to access an instance of B (e.g. `print a.b`) I receive a DoesNotExist exception.  When there is a DB row corresponding to the relation it works.  This is on django 1.5.

Simplified model definition off the top of my head (not tested in this form):

```
class A:
    ...

class B:
    a = models.OneToOneField(A, related_name='a')
    name = models.TextField(...)

fields = ['b__name']
a = A.object.filter(pk=id).selected_related(*fields)
print(a.b)
```

Table B has a foreign key of a_id.

My reason for the question was to determine if there was a cleaner way to do this via an API rather than catching an exception.

Comment: Could you show your model definitions?

Comment: Why would you not want to catch B.DoesNotExist? That's pretty standard exception handling.

Comment: Does your ForeignKey field allow nulls?

Comment: My foreign key allows nulls, correct.

Comment: "That's pretty standard exception handling."  That's bad API which lead to ugly code.  Exception catching is just that, an exceptional case.  If there's no API to inspect whether a relationship exists then fine, just want someone to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, firstly the attribute "related_name" is used to refer the current object from the reversed foreign key object, so the model definition should be something like :

```
class A:
   ...

class B:
    a = models.OneToOneField(A, related_name='alias_for_b')
    name = models.TextField(...)
```

and the validation code could be simply:

```
if hasattr(a, 'alias_for_b'):
    print(a.b) or print(a.alias_for_b)
```

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have your instance of `A` `a`. As you correctly say you can access the related instance of `B` `b` with something like `print(a.b)` (Python 3 syntax). If it's possible that there will be no related item and you don't want the user to get an error then you need to wrap that call to `b` up in something. Something like:

```
try:
    print(a.b)
except:
    print('Nothing to see here')
```

That checks for `b`'s presence before trying to present it, and won't do so if it's not there.

Alternatively, you could approach this from the other direction. Given an instance `a` you could look up `B.objects.filter(your_relation_name=a)`. That way won't involve any error catching, just a blank queryset if no such `b` exists.

Comment: Why catching Exception would be better than catching DoesNotExist?

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned about efficiency, it's more error prone as it catches all exceptions, even unexpected ones.

Comment: My intent was to not have to catch an exception.  I'm looking for an API.  Seems strange this isn't possible without catching an exception.

Comment: Understood, I've added a different way to do this that's closer to what you describe. Haven't tested it as I'm away from my dev machine but it should work.